# cannot read property of undefined when calling method on collection mongodb

Tags: mongodb, export, database

I'm trying to work out the basic infrastructure of a post ajax call to save something in my db, under a collection named 'ranges'.

1. When I just run node connection.js I get 
   " Cannot read property 'ranges' of undefined", did I create that collection wrong?
2. Is it necessary to create it before inserting? I read somewhere that MongdoDB should create the collection for you if doesn't exist.
3. Should I db.close() my connection function at some point?
4. When I export the DB, does it automatically export the reference to the collection underneath it?

**connection.js**

```
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
var db = MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
if (err) {
  console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
} else {
  console.log('Connection established to', url);
  db.createCollection("ranges");

}});

doSomething = function() {
db.ranges.insert ({"hello" : "world"});
};

module.exports = db;
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static('/public'));
app.use(cors());
var db = require('./connection');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send('Got a GET request');
 });

app.post('/', function(req, res){
res.send('Got a POST request');

});


app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("Server started successfully at Port 3000!");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - `db` is undefined because because you don't wait for the connection to be ready before exporting it. Perhaps it'd be better to connect after requiring db in order to be able to perform actions after the callback

Besides, `createCollection` is an async operation, so you are probably calling the insert method before it gets to be created. You should so something like:

```
db.createCollection("ranges", function(err, collection){
    collection.insert({"hello" : "world"});
});
```

But if `ranges` collection is already created you should have no issues.

2 - Mongo will create the collections for you when you insert documents into them, but sometimes you can come to errors like the one you are having, as the collection does not exist you will have null references.(Now I'm not sure if the driver is intelligent enough to create it for you if it's not there)

3 - Although it's not completely necessary, sometimes it is good to close the connection. I usually do it when receiving a `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT`. See example:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
  db.close()
  process.exit(0);
});
```

4 - Yes, but make sure they are being created first (remember from the first item that it's an async operation)

(Another tip, check[mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/), perhaps it will make things easier)

Comment: 1. I checked my DB and I have the "ranges" collection created before I call on the doSomething function to insert my document in it.

Comment: Hummm taking a better look at your code, I see the the module.exports is called, but the db connection process is asynchronous. I'll update my answer

Comment: Ok, you were changes. It works now (I upvoted but I don't have enough reputation point for it to be displayed).

Comment: Nice. Oh ok, can you plse accept it then? (The check symbol below the votes)